# Unifying Local and Repository Generics type return into the repository pattern

Tags: android, generics, repository-pattern, rx-java2, android-room

I want to call from my `viewModel class` the repository `getPosts` using a Repository pattern.

Both `getPostsArrayfromLocalRoomDB`[ the call from Retrofit] and `getPostsArrayfromLocalRoomDB`[the call from Room db] get successfully called from the `viewModel`

I implemented a Repository Interface and a `RepositoryImpl class`
with this **Remote Retrofit** call in the Repository:

```
 @Override
public Flowable<List<PostFromJsonModel>> getPostsArrayFromRetrofitRemote(String tags) {
//notice <PostFromJsonModel>

      return postsFromRemoteDataSource.getAllRemote(tags).toFlowable(BackpressureStrategy.BUFFER);
}
```

and this **Local RoomDB** that calls Room DB:

```
 @Override
public Flowable<List<PostFromRoomDB>> getPostsArrayfromLocalRoomDB(String tags) {
//notice <PostFromRoomDB>
    return postsfromLocalDataSource.getAllLocalDb();
}
```

Now I want an agnostic call `getPosts` so that I can insert inside this method my business logic to call the DB and the `REST API`,
the problem is that I don't know what I should return:

what_I_should_return?

```
public   getPosts(String tags){

//I know the business logic here, no need to suggest this

}
```

I tried `Flowable<List<?>, Flowable<List<T>` and so on but I have not clue how I should combine the two generic types `PostFromJsonModel` and `PostFromRoomDB`  to unify the call.

Answer (score 0):

Got it, I just needed to return a simple `Flowable` without parameters. The funny thing is that as I have a subscribe in the view needed to declare Flowable in the viewModel.